# Unable to access Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, wso2

I'm having problems accessing my application on ASK.
So I basically used this file to create a deployment, service and ingress and I exposed the port 9443, yet I can't connect to my application, please help.

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
       name: wso2-app
    spec:
       replicas: 1
        selector:
          matchLabels:
        app: wso2-app
     template:
        metadata:
      labels:
        app: wso2-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wso2-app
        image: wso2/wso2am
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9443
        - containerPort: 8243
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wso2-app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 9443
  selector:
    app: wso2-app
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wso2-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: wso2-dns-952d0c51.hcp.australiaeast.azmk8s.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: wso2-app
            port: 
              number: 9443
```

Comment: What's the response you get when trying to access it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.